# Is Int 1 always implicitly converted to 1 day?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, types, implicit-conversion

In SQL Server there are rules for implicitly converting data types.

On [this documentation page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/data-type-conversion-database-engine?view=sql-server-ver16) there is a table about what conversions are possible.

On [this documentation page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/data-type-precedence-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16) we can see what gets converted to what.

When I implicitly convert an integer to datetime the interval implicitly assumed is 1 day. Therefore the following returns the same time tomorrow:

```
select getdate() + 1
```

However, one could argue that 1 should be an hour or a minute. I tried to find in the documentation where it is specified that the interval for implicit conversion to datetime is always 24 hours. Right at the beginning of the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/datetime-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16) of datetime it says:

> Defines a date that is combined with a time of day with fractional
> seconds that is based on a 24-hour clock.

But I don't feel this to be precise and clear enough to convince somebody that the integer 1 will unchangeably represent 1 day if implicitly converted.

So is there a place where Microsoft makes this clear?

Comment: This is more likely a "hang over" from SQL Server's predecessor, Sybase. None of the "new" date and time data types have this "feature". `SELECT SYSDATETIME() + 1` will generate an error.

Comment: I've been developing software for a long time and I had no idea this was even a thing, probably because it's so obviously ambiguous as you've already noted. Why don't you just use `dateadd` explicitly and then you wouldn't need to ask this question at all?

Comment: Honestly, just don't rely on the functionality, especially *because* it doesn't work with the "modern" data types (they were added in 2005, so they are hardly "new"). If you want to add/substract a period of time to a date (and time) value, use `DATEADD`, then it's not ambiguous: `DATEADD(DAY, 1, GETDATE())` is clearly adding a *1 day* to the value `GETDATE()`. It also works regardless of the data type, so if at some point in the future your employer decides that 1/300 of a second isn't accurate enough and they switch to a `datetime2(4)`, you don't suddenly end up with errors.

Comment: I don't know why, but the float value of datetime is number of days since 19000101, so i guess it's logical that adding 1 to that value increments the date by one day as well. Since you asked, you should not use this feature, although i have to admit i rather use it a lot, but i'm an oldtimer and it saves a lot of keystrokes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In answer to your question *"Is Int 1 always implicitly converted to 1 day?"*: No. It is for `(small)datetime`, but for modern data types it will generate an error.

---

As for *why* it's `1` for a day most likely it's something that predates SQL Server and likely comes from Sybase (though I have no way of confirming this). Why `1` was chosen as a day, I don't know. Maybe it's because another application at the time did something similar; Excel does the same, for example, but their numbers don't align (`0` is `1900-01-00` and `1` is `1900-01-01`, however, it later drifts more due treating 1900 as having a leap year, so today is `45371` in SQL Server, but `45373` in Excel). If it wasn't because of some other application, it was likely arbitrary.

Like you mention in the comments, code like `GETDATE() + 1` could easily be seen as ambiguous; what is `1` as a `datetime`? A user could easily be forgiven for expecting it to be something else (such as a second like with epochs).

This behaviour is not present in the modern date and time data types, `date`, `datetime2` and `datetimeoffset` (and `time`). The data types do not allow for conversions from a numerical values to them, explicit or implicit. If you tried to add `1` to such a date you would get an error:

```sql
SELECT SYSDATETIME() + 1;
```

> Operand type clash: datetime2 is incompatible with int

In truth, the best thing to do is be explicit. There is a function for adding/subtracting time periods to a date (and time) value: `DATEADD`. The function works for all the date and time data types ("new" and "old"), and the syntax is *very* explicit:

```sql
SELECT DATEADD(DAY, 1, SYSDATETIME());
```

No one, now, can be forgiven for thinking the above is adding anything other than 1 day to the current value of system date and time.

Comment: Way back when SQL Server was forked from/based on Sybase code history for the TSQL and it is still in there https://infocenter.sybase.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.sybase.help.sqlanywhere.12.0.1/dbreference/getdate-function.html and I see the 2003 copyright here https://infocenter.sybase.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.sybase.dc32300_1251/html/sqlug/X69127.htm but it was there quite a bit before that.

Comment: @MarkSchultheiss I can't see anything about implicit numerical conversions to a `datetime` in either of those links; they are both about `GETDATE()` and *only* `GETDATE()`. The question was more expansive than about that single function.

Comment: Yes, just some background info re: the sybase parts. FWIW this is a nice answer here! I saw something re: datetime and datetime2 on I THINK it was some release notes at some point with regard to this but it was a good while back hence I forgot where I saw it regarding conversions.

Answer (score 1):

`CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` is the ANSI compatible function and returns the same value as the SQL Server function `GETDATE()` both of which derive from the operating system from the computer on which they run. `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` works with other ANSI compatible databases whereas `GETDATE()` does not.

Unless I need a UTC date I use the `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` form since it really IS a timestamp with date/time - unless it is assigned for example: Both these work but are just the Date type not DateTime

```
DECLARE @MYDATE DATE = GETDATE();
DECLARE @MYDATE DATE = CURRENT_TIMESTAMP;
```

It is not just an integer as these all work in SQL Server.

```
SELECT
    CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
    CURRENT_TIMESTAMP + 1,
    CURRENT_TIMESTAMP - 1,
    CURRENT_TIMESTAMP + 1.5,
    CURRENT_TIMESTAMP - 1.5,
    GETDATE(),
    GETDATE() + 1,
    GETDATE() + 1.5,
    GETUTCDATE(),
    GETUTCDATE() -5,
    DATEADD(DAY, 1, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP),
    DATEADD(DAY, -1, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP),
    DATEADD(DAY, -1.5, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP)
    ;
```

I always recommend the use of the `DATEADD(DAY, 1, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP)` for clarity of purpose and as this also makes it simpler when you also need hours `DATEADD(HOUR, 8, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP)` `DATEADD(MINUTE, 1400, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP)` or other datetime adjustments;

Answer (score 0):

The answer to your question is yes. But don't rely on it. You can also add 6 hours with +0.25, because thats how the internal representation is in SQL Server. It looks like a lot of documentation is cleaned up, but I have seen old documents specifying the internal representation.

```
select cast(cast('31 dec 1899' as datetime) as float)
select cast(cast('1 jan 1900' as datetime) as float)
select cast(1.25 as datetime)
select cast(cast('2 jan 1900' as datetime) as float)
```

Many years ago I remember misusing this by casting a lot of dates to float, doing average and casting back to get the average date. But I don't think I would do that today.

Answer (score 0):

One handy tool for exploring data type issues is [`SQL_VARIANT_PROPERTY`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/sql-variant-property-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16):

```
select sql_variant_property( GetDate(), 'BaseType' ); -- datetime.
select sql_variant_property( 1, 'BaseType' ); -- int.
```

If you combine the two in an *expression*:

```
select sql_variant_property( GetDate() + 1, 'BaseType' ); -- datetime.
```

As you have found, the rules for *data type precedence* and *data type conversion* show that an implicit conversion will occur from `int` to `datetime` in the previous expression. An explicit conversion to the target data type should provide the same result:

```
select sql_variant_property( Cast( 1 as DateTime ), 'BaseType' ); -- datetime.
select Cast( 1 as DateTime ); -- 1900-01-02 00:00:00.000.
```

In a delightfully circular way this is documented as:

[Expression Results](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/expressions-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16#expression-results):

> When two expressions are combined by using arithmetic, bitwise, or
> string operators, the operator determines the resulting data type.

[+ (Addition)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/add-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16#result-types):

> Returns the data type of the argument with the higher precedence. For more information, see [Data Type Precedence (Transact-SQL)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/data-type-precedence-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16).

[Data type precedence](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/data-type-precedence-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16):
The table shows `datetime` (6) is a higher precedence than `int` (16).

Which leaves you back at [Data type conversion](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/data-type-conversion-database-engine?view=sql-server-ver16).

That *ought* to mean that the code samples show the behavior to be expected and that `1` will be implicitly converted to one day as a `datetime`. Explicit documentation is not always available.

Aside: Another useful place to check is [Constants](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/constants-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16). It is silent on the issue at hand.